# Setup a website using Java with Database access

Tags: java, xml, spring, jsp

I am trying to learn and better understand the process for communicating java with web content.

Currently I have a finished java project that communicates with a database.  I also have a website template I have created purely from hard coded html and css. My next goal is to take my java project to a higher level and incorporate my project with my website.

I have no idea where to start and have little to no knowledge on jsp's or xml files. Others have told me to implement a Spring MVC framework. If anyone can share there input it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just google Spring MVC tutorial, you will find tons of them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes If you already know Java I would definitely advise you to go with Spring and Hibernate. I would always recommend the beginner guide to Spring which is this one **Spring MVC: Beginner's GuideJun by G, Amuthan** it will show you step by step guide on how to step up your environment. Googling yes you can but don't be overwhelmed with too many resources being out there....For the front page you will have many options Spring allows you to add different dependencies on pom.xml file if you want to use. I have worked with both JSP and Thymeleaf. I would say go with Thymeleaf ... may be I am biased.

Good Luck!